# Посоветуете хостин для долгосрочного выполнения скрипта(2-5 дня)

Tags: хостинг

Посоветуете хостинг на котором есть возможность долгосрочного выполнения скрипта. Предположительное время выполнения от 2 до 5 дней.

Comment: Вы что там, алмазы майните пять дней беспрерывно? Такие долгосрочные скрипты -- это вероятно плохо спроектированные решения и нужно заменять одно выполнение длиной в часах на серию отдельных мелких выполнений. Будет много более устойчивее к сбоям. будет проще выделять ресурсы.

Comment: Вопрос чересчур общий: не указан язык программирования, на котором выполняется скрипт, требования к ОС.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какой язык программирования. Возможно Вам подойдет Heroku. Это облачная PaaS-платформа, поддерживающая ряд языков программирования. Идеально подходит при применении этих языков программирования: Java, Node.js, Scala, Clojure, Python, Go и PHP. Сама платформа: https://www.heroku.com/. Также статья про Heroku на Хабре: https://habr.com/post/232679/

Comment: как называются подобные  сервисы? Хочу поискать другие варианты

Comment: @evseygames, а какой язык Вам нужен?

Comment: python. Скрипт уже готов, мне нужно просто его запустить в подобном сервисе

Comment: Есть Microsoft Azure, она вроде поддерживает Python.

Comment: Также я бы попробовал Amazon WS: https://aws.amazon.com/. Самая быстроразвивающаяся платформа на данный момент.